# Learning C* Algebra via Problems

Tags: soft-question, operator-algebras

I have been reading the book "C*-Algebras and Operator Theory" by G.J.Murphy. I have almost finished reading the first two chapters. I was wondering if someone could suggest me some book/Lecture notes/source with some good problems to go over. Murphy's book has some. But they are at the end of the chapter and very few.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the book *An Introduction to Operator Algebras* written by Kehe Zhu is very well suited to learn about $C^*$-algebras actively. The book consists of 26 (very) short chapters and each of these chapters contains several well-chosen exercises.